# NSFetchRequest two columns and sum

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

Given `Calls` table:

`+--------+--------+----------+
| caller | callee | duration |
+--------+--------+----------+
|   A    |    B   |     3    |
|   B    |    C   |     1    |
|   C    |    A   |     2    |
|   B    |    A   |     5    |
+--------+--------+----------+`

Desired output:

`+------------+-------+
| subscriber | total |
+------------+-------+
|     A      |  10   |
|     B      |   9   |
|     C      |   3   |
+------------+-------+`

How to setup a NSFetchRequest to obtain the desired output ?

Comment: Core Data is not a SQL database , it's an object graph manager. Fetch all objects you need then do the grouping and summation in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve it somehow (the code below is not the actual code in my app but a sketch). It's a "hybrid" solution, between a fetch-only (which I doubt is possible, CoreData lacks union) and a full in-memory one.

```
class Subscriber:NSObject {

@objc dynamic var subscriber = 0
@objc dynamic var total = 0

init(dictionary: NSDictionary) {
    if let s = dictionary["caller"] as? Int { subscriber = s} 
    if let t = dictionary["total"] as? Int { total = t }
    super.init()
}

init(dictionary: NSDictionary, _:Bool) {
    if let s = dictionary["callee"] as? Int { subscriber = s} 
    if let t = dictionary["total"] as? Int { total = t }
    super.init()
}
```

To obtain an array of Subscriber objects in a do...catch:

```
let req_a = NSFetchRequest<NSDictionary>(entityName:"Call")

let durExp = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "duration")

let sumDesc = NSExpressionDescription()
sumDesc.expression = NSExpression(forFunction: "sum:", arguments: [durExp])
sumDesc.name = "total"
sumDesc.expressionResultType = .integer64AttributeType

req_a.propertiesToGroupBy = ["caller"]
req_a.propertiesToFetch = ["caller", sumDesc]
req_a.resultType = .dictionaryResultType       

let req_b = NSFetchRequest<NSDictionary>(entityName:"Call")

req_b.propertiesToGroupBy = ["callee"]
req_b.propertiesToFetch = ["callee", sumDesc]
req_b.resultType = .dictionaryResultType

var subscriberResults_a = try theMOC.fetch(req_a).map { return Subscriber(dictionary: $0) }
var subscriberResults_b = try theMOC.fetch(req_b).map { return Subscriber(dictionary: $0, true) }

/// Add values from duplicates
subscriberResults_a = subscriberResults_a?.map { a -> Subscriber in
     guard let b = subscriberResults_b?.first(where: { $0.subscriber == a.subscriber }) else { return a }
     a.total += b.total
     return a
}

/// Filter out duplicates
subscriberResults_b = subscriberResults_b?.filter({ b -> Bool in
     if let found = subscriberResults_a?.contains (where: { $0.subscriber == b.subscriber }) { return !found }
     return true
})

subscriberArray = subscriberResults_a! +  subscriberResults_b!
```

Still looking for a better solution.